# I have an slack bot, and somehow i need to authenticate the users of the bot(actuall individual users) to a backend service

Tags: slack, slack-api, solid

in short i need it so that my bot can do authenticated requests
think of as slack trello app
that at first it tries to login with users trello account to get the requred permitions...

- i'm listening on messages,
- have a seprate routes that hanles the login proccess
- need to the bot inctance to be authenticated
- this is the repo if you want more info on it: https://github.com/pondersource/solid-slack-bridge